# Insert non-repeating data into table

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, on-duplicate-key

I've got a file that I've succesfully updated to a table. Now, I'm required to do it again in a way that the data is not being repeated.

my target table:

```
mysql> show columns from MARCAS;
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID_MARCA | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| MARCA    | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

So what I did was to create a temporary table and loaded data from the file into it.

code used:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempe LIKE marcas;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE myfile.txt
INTO TABLE MARCAS
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '#' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(ID_MARCA, MARCA, @ignore1, @ignore2, @ignore3);
```

All fine here. The problem starts when I am trying to be smart and use 'ON DUPLICATE KEY'(like it was sugested here) to insert data from temporary table into table MARCAS as so data does not repeat itself. The code I used was:

```
INSERT into MARCAS select * from TEMPE on duplicate key update MARCA=values(MARCA);
```

The result:

```
mysql> select * from MARCAS;
+----------+---------+
| ID_MARCA | MARCA   |
+----------+---------+
|        1 | PICASSA |
|        2 | PICASSA |
|        3 | C4      |
|        4 | C4      |
|        5 | C3      |
|        6 | C3      |
|        7 | C2      |
|        8 | C2      |
|        9 | MONDEO  |
|       10 | MONDEO  |
|       11 | S-MAX   |
|       12 | S-MAX   |
|       13 | CIVIC   |
|       14 | CIVIC   |
|       15 | ACCORD  |
|       16 | ACCORD  |
|       17 | CLS     |
|       18 | 900     |
|       19 | LEON    |
|       20 | LEON    |
|       21 | IBIZA   |
|       22 | IBIZA   |
|       23 | 307     |
|       24 | 307     |
|       25 | 308     |
|       26 | 308     |
|       27 | 407     |
|       28 | 407     |
|       29 | 408     |
|       30 | 408     |
|       31 | MEGANE  |
|       32 | MEGANE  |
|       33 | PASSAT  |
|       34 | PASSAT  |
|       35 | GOLF    |
|       36 | GOLF    |
|       37 | TOUAREG |
+----------+---------+
```

Not impressed with myself. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's caused by the fact that you don't have a UNIQUE index on your MARCA column.

```
alter table MARCAS add unique(MARCA);
```

> If you specify ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, and a row is inserted that
>   would cause a duplicate value in a **UNIQUE** index or **PRIMARY KEY**, MySQL
>   performs an UPDATE of the old row.

source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Please also note that it's also possible to do INSERT IGNORE or A REPLACE when you do a load data.

Comment: thanks! as usual very helpful. :-) what I also noticed is that my data is being loaded from the second column in file. First being completly ignored. Any reason for that?

Comment: and it was a pleasure to be of help. all the best with your project

Comment: oops, looks like I had missed part of your comment. Really sorry about that but glad to hear all is well

Answer (score 0):

May you get some idea from this

```
INSERT INTO MARCAS(field1)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT field1 FROM MARCAS WHERE name = 'field1'
) LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: that's going to be really slow